# Add/Remove programs: what happens when an app installs incorrectly?

Tags: installation, windows-registry, uninstall, debug, windows-installer

I'm a developer, and the installshields I create deploy 'debugsupport.msi', which is the visual studio 2010 debug support executable.

However, when I attempt to run it, it says it's already installed (it may be the case, but it doesn't show up in add/remove programs).

My goal is to remove it, so I can successfully try my installs out.

My problem is that on my machine, apparently 'debugsupport.msi' installed correctly, but didn't show up in add/remove programs.

I tried right clicking on the msi, and attempting to repair and uninstall, but they both say the product is not installed.

When I try to install, it says 'already installed'.

Where can I find the traces of this msi and wipe them off my pc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about trying an uninstaller program, such as [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/)?

I've had pretty good results with that cleaning up failed installs on my own system.

Comment: That worked!  It showed debugsupport.msi in there.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the cmd line, `cd` to wherever your `msi` file is located ad try:

```
MSIEXEC /x yourfile.msi
```

see if this will get it to remove itself.

Also see this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec

Comment: That gave the same error that right clicking\uninstall did

Comment: see edit for more info